# Set cookie only for the given domain

Tags: javascript, cookies, subdomain

I set a cookie like this:

```
  document.cookie = 'cookie-consent' + '=' + value
                + ';expires=' + date.toUTCString()
                + ';domain=sunfire-website.com';
```

This works fine! As you can see:

[image]

But - the domain is `.sunfire-website.com`.

That means it is also for subdomains.

For my cookie consent I want not to set it for all domains but **just for the given domain**.

How can I do this - because I never set the '.' by myself.

Comment: What does the cookie report as it's `path`?

Comment: its just `/` as path

Comment: Try setting the path to the specific domain you want it to be available on

Comment: I don't quite understand. Its `/` (at the whole site) on this domain ...

Comment: It's been a bit since I messed with cookies, but from a quick search engine lookup, some articles were stating that setting the path to `/` allows it to match against all subdomains, and is what you would want to do to make it do that.  So if that is true, conversely to make it not do that, you'd want it to not be `/`

Comment: This link suggests you can't set a cookie on a domain without including the subdomains: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55790/setting-cookies-only-on-the-naked-domain

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
  document.cookie = 'cookie-consent' + '=' + value
                + ';expires=' + date.toUTCString()
                + ';domain=sunfire-website.com';
```

To

```
  document.cookie = 'cookie-consent' + '=' + value
                + ';expires=' + date.toUTCString()
                + ';domain=www.sunfire-website.com';
```

Will work because www signals the 'main' domain

Comment: No. It just fails. When I do `+ ';domain=www.' + COOKIE_DOMAIN`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

When you want to set the cookie for **all subdomains** just set the `domain`.
If not (**without subdomains**) just don't set a domain.

The actual domain will be used:

```
document.cookie = 'cookie-consent' + '=' + value
                + ';expires=' + date.toUTCString();
```

Gives the right thing:

[image]

Thank you for your help.